# Data not being written to file

Tags: python, pdf, web-crawler

I am writing a python program that uses scrapy spider to crawl a website and looks for pdf files. Once a pdf file is found, it downloads the pdf file to a folder and opens and reads the pdf to grab info from it (author, title, number of pages and if the document is tagged or not). This data is written in CSV file.

Everything seems to work fine, but when I open the CSV file, there is not nearly as much data in it as I expected. For example, I will crawl a site and find 40 pdf files, but the CSV has entries for only 14 pdf's.

pdfspider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
import urllib.parse as urlparse
import os.path
import validators
import csv
from .. info import isTagged
from .. get_metadata import get_data


class PdfspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'pdfspider' 
    allowed_domain = input('Enter the domain name of the website to be crawled (domain of https://google.com is "google"): ')
    allowed_domains = [allowed_domain]
    #need domain to name folder pdfs will be put into
    global domain
    domain = allowed_domains[0]
    global start
    start = input('Enter the url of the page you wish to start the crawl on (include http/https): ')
    start_urls = [start]
    global base_path
    base_path = input('Where do you wish to save the folder containing the pdfs?: ')

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        base_url = start        
        for a in response.xpath('//a[@href]/@href'):
            link = a.extract()
            if link.endswith('.pdf'):
                link = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, link)
                yield Request(link, callback=self.save_pdf)

    def create_csv(self):
        header = ['location', 'title', 'author', '# of pages', 'tagged?']
        filename = base_path + '/' +domain + '/' + domain + '.csv'
        f = open(filename, 'x')
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)
        f.close()


    def save_pdf(self, response):
        url=response.url
        if response.status == 200:
            save_dir = base_path + '/' + domain
            isExist = os.path.exists(save_dir)
            if not isExist:
                # Create a new directory because it does not exist 
                os.makedirs(save_dir)
            csvFile = domain + '.csv'
            csvPath = save_dir + '/' + csvFile
            csvPathExist = os.path.exists(csvPath)
            if not csvPathExist:
                self.create_csv()
            file = response.url.split('/')[-1]
            full_path = os.path.join(save_dir, file)
            with open(full_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.body)
            metaData = get_data(full_path)
            is_tagged = isTagged(full_path)
            row = [url, metaData[0], metaData[1], metaData[2], is_tagged]
            self.add_to_csv(row)
            
        else:
            print(f"Failed to load pdf: {url}")

    def add_to_csv(self,row):
        filename = base_path + '/' +domain + '/' + domain + '.csv'
        f = open(filename, "a")
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(row)
        f.close()
```

info.py

```
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.pdfdevice import TagExtractor
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import BytesIO

def isTagged(path, password=''):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = BytesIO()
    
    try:
        try:
            device = TagExtractor(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec='utf-8')
        except:
            print('Not utf-8.')
        try:
            device = TagExtractor(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec='ascii')
        except:
            print('Not ascii.')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    maxpages = 100
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    contents = retstr.getvalue().decode()
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()

    # check if common proprietary Acrobat tags are in the response
    tags = ["<b\'Part\'", "</b\'Sect\'", "</b\'Art\'", "<b'Content'", "<b\'Artifact\'"]
    for tag in tags:
        if tag in contents:
            return 'tagged'
            break
        else:
            continue
    return 'not tagged'
```

get_metadata.py

```
from pdfminer3.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer3.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages

def get_data(file):
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    author = doc.info[0]["Author"]
    title = doc.info[0]["Title"]
    numPages = len(list(extract_pages(file)))

    return title, author, numPages
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? This is my first python program so I am pretty green. I am running python 3.9.7

Comment: You should debug your code first (maybe try jupyter if you're new to python) and only once you've identified the problem and can't solve it yourself post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you! I been trying to debug with print statements but the crawler outputs so much data its hard to fid the statements. I'll look at jupyter